# for loop on multiple paired files

Tags: bash

I have a set of paired end files named as

```
D2_WT_mock1_1.fastq D2_WT_mock1_2.fastq
D2_KO_inf3_1.fastq  D2_KO_inf3_2.fastq
D6_KO_inf3_1.fastq  D6_KO_inf3_2.fastq
```

And, I would like to perform a command that requires both input as follows:

```
rule.py D2_WT_mock1_1.fastq D2_WT_mock1_2.fastq -o D2_WT_mock1
```

Where the two paired end files are used as input, and the output name is also indicated.

I tried this

```
for f in *_1.fastq; do
command.py "$f" "${f%_1.fastq}_2.fastq" -o $f;
done
```

but since the filenames are in the format of

```
    File_something_something_1.fastq
```

how do I make sure the correct corresponding paired file is used as input to the _1.fastq each time? Also how to name the output as just the prefix term for example D2_WT_mock1, and not the whole file name as in my command.

Comment: Is this what you want? `for f in *_1.fastq; do command.py "$f" "${f%_1.fastq}_2.fastq" -o {f%_1.fastq}; done` Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean with "this does not work"? What do you want to happen and what happens instead? The `for` loop processes one pair of files after the other, not all at once.

Comment: @Bodo in the second string he wants to repeat the found filename, but with the '1' in the middle changed to a '2' (ie the 'paired' file)

Comment: @mcalex Looks like Bodo's answer does that.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks, in what I posted, I missed out $"{f%_1.fastq}" to just get the prefix before _1.fastq as the output name.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while read line1; do
    while read line2; do
        echo -n "$line2 "
    done <<< $(ls -1 ${line1%_*}*)
    echo "-o ${line1%_*}"     
done <<< $(ls -1 *1.fastq) |\
while read line3; do
   echo "rule.py $line3"
done
```

output

```
rule.py D2_KO_inf3_1.fastq D2_KO_inf3_2.fastq -o D2_KO_inf3
rule.py D2_WT_mock1_1.fastq D2_WT_mock1_2.fastq -o D2_WT_mock1
rule.py D6_KO_inf3_1.fastq D6_KO_inf3_2.fastq -o D6_KO_inf3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *_1.fastq; do
   command.py "$f" "${f/1.fastq/2.fastq}" -o "${f/_1.fastq}";
done
```